# Selected option link popup in lightbox format

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, form-submit

I made an autocomplete drop down search box using form and jquery.
When users select certain option and click the submit button, it's directed to a linked webpage.

After users hit the submit button, I want to show the linked html webpage using lightbox style popup window or dialogue.

May i know how to intergrate lightbox(thickbox) popup results triggered by clicking submit buttion in dropdown menu?

Here is my Code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Javascript image dropdown - basic</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sample.css" />
    <script src="../js/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <msdropdown> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/msdropdown/dd.css" />
    <script src="../js/msdropdown/jquery.dd.min.js"></script>
    <!-- </msdropdown> -->
    </head>

    <body>

    <form name="frmdata">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5" class="tblWhite">
    <tr>
    <td valign="top">
    <select id="payments" name="payments" style="width:250px;">
    <option value="#" data-description="Choos your payment gateway">Payment Gateway</option>
    <option value="help.html" data-image="../images/msdropdown/icons/Amex-56.png" data-description="My life. My card...">Amex</option>
    <option value="help.html" data-image="../images/msdropdown/icons/Discover-56.png" data-description="It pays to Discover...">Discover</option>
    <option value="help.html" data-image="../images/msdropdown/icons/Mastercard-56.png" data-title="For everything else..." data-description="For everything else...">Mastercard</option>
    <option value="help.html" data-image="../images/msdropdown/icons/Cash-56.png" data-description="Sorry not available..." disabled="true">Cash on devlivery</option>
    <option value="help.html" data-image="../images/msdropdown/icons/Visa-56.png" data-description="All you need...">Visa</option>
    <option value="help.html" data-image="../images/msdropdown/icons/Paypal-56.png" data-description="Pay and get paid...">Paypal</option>
    </select> &nbsp;
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td valign="bottom"><input type="button" onClick="location=document.frmdata.payments.options[document.frmdata.payments.selectedIndex].value;" value="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>

    </table>
    </form>

   <script>
   //var tc;
   $(document).ready(function(e) {
 $("#payments").msDropdown({visibleRows:4});
 $("#tech").msDropdown().data("dd");//{animStyle:'none'} /{animStyle:'slideDown'} {animStyle:'show'}        
//no use
try {
    var pages = $("#pages").msDropdown({on:{change:function(data, ui) {
                                               var val = data.value;
                                            if(val!="")
                                                window.location = val;
                                        }}}).data("dd");

    var pagename = document.location.pathname.toString();
    pagename = pagename.split("/");
    pages.setIndexByValue(pagename[pagename.length-1]);
    $("#ver").html(msBeautify.version.msDropdown);
} catch(e) {
    //console.log(e);   
}

$("#ver").html(msBeautify.version.msDropdown);
    });

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/)  like,

```
$("input[type='button']").click(function() {
    $.fancybox({
        'padding' : 0,
        'href' : $('#payments option:selected').data('image'),
        'title' : 'Image Demo',
    });
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AB4a8/)

**Note:** Use `Jquery version < 1.9` as this `fancybox plugin` uses [$.browser()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/) which is removed in `jquery 1.9 version` or read [jquery 1.9 Upgrade Guide](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/)

Comment: thank you so much for your advice and demo.After following your guide, I could execute fancybox popup after selection. According to your example, I can show the data-image as a popup result. I want to show the option value url as a result in popup instead of data-image. Could you help me how to to it? This is the last step that I want to execute.

Comment: Change `href` like, `'href' : $('#payments').val(),`